# Laravel returns 500 internal server and 404 on routes after deploying to Amazon EC2

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, apache2

I like to ask help on how to fix the 500 internal server and 404 when using laravel routes after deploying it to Amazon AWS.

[image]

I tried to clear the cache and restarting the apache2 but no luck.

Also I do change the permissions of the folders
[image]

I also change the `000-default.conf` file
[image]

Until now, no luck on my side. Did I miss something or do I need change some configurations? Please let me know and Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason is that composer is using your localhost configuration you've to reconfigure your laravelapp on your ec2 instance. Try these commands in order:

`1. composer dump-autoload`

`2. PHP artisan config:cache`

`3. PHP artisan optimize`

and then check your laravel application for your ec2 instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked! but my only problem is the route. When I tried it in postman, it returns 404 not found. Do you have an idea to fix it?

Comment: check for available routes using `php artisan route:list` if the was CLI returns your API routes then it should work otherwise you need to use `php artisan route:cache`

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a problem with the php version. My project was using 7.4 but the ec2 ubuntu machine i was using was version 22 which was installing php 8.1. I created a new ec2 machine of version 20.04 ubuntu os. And installed php7.4 and all other php dependencies at 7.4 version. One more problem that i was facing related to this was the write access permission to the app/storage/logs folder. I resolved this using the "chmod -R 777 /var/www/myprojectname/app/storage" command. Hope this is helpful